# Is the largest gap between consecutive primes less than the first $27,000$ integers equal to $52?$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is the largest gap between consecutive primes below the first $27,000$ integers equal to $52?$

At what point does a gap greater than $52$ occur?

I tried analyzing a formula due to Maynard, Tao, and Ford to find the answers:

$$ \frac{\log X \log \log X \log \log \log \log X}{\log \log \log X} $$

I'm getting a negative number from this formula so I'm having trouble finding the answer.

Comment: That formula is only for very large $X$. Keep in mind that in number theory, $27000$ is very small.

Comment: oh okay, is there a more appropriate formula for small numbers? Is there a good asymptotic formula?

Comment: A quick script finds that the first gap of length $\geq 52$ is that between $19\,609$ and $19\,661$.

Comment: is there an asymptotic formula?

Comment: The expression in the question *is* an asymptotic formula for large $X$. As you can  see from Steven's answer the size of the smallest primes bounding a gap of size $\geq N$ as a function of $N$ jumps dramatically, so we shouldn't expect a simple formula that approximates the values well for small $N$.

Comment: ok thanks very much

Comment: There is always a gap of at least $p_n-1$ at a number less than or equal to  $P_{n-1}\#-p_n$

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of "record" prime gaps
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results.
Those are the prime gaps where there is no larger prime gap before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function:

$$\Psi_g(X)= e^{\frac{g}{\log(X)}}=X $$

provides a decent measure for the largest gap $g$ between consecutive primes less than $X.$

It is not the best, because it is off by $52$ when $X=27,000$ and off by $417$ when $X=2^{64}.$

Answer (score 4):

The first gap of $52$ is:

$$p_{2226}-p_{2225}=19661-19609=52$$

The first gap larger than $52$ is:

$$p_{3386}-p_{3385}=31469-31397=72$$